# Background triangle instead of circle JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement the following effect on my site: [AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/index2.html)

But instead of circles I want triangles that go upwards. I have searched Stack Overflow and tried a couple things, but it did not quite work.

```js
  (function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, triangles, target, animateHeader = true;
    var colors = ['72,35,68', '43,81,102', '66,152,103', '250,178,67', '224,33,48'];

    // Main
    initHeader();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: 0, y: height};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create particles
        triangles = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width*0.5; x++) {
            var c = new Triangle();
            triangles.push(c);
        }
        animate();
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in triangles) {
                triangles[i].draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function Triangle() {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.coords = [{},{},{}];
            _this.pos = {};
            init();
        })();

        function init() {
            _this.pos.x = Math.random()*width;
            _this.pos.y = height+Math.random()*100;
            _this.alpha = 0.1+Math.random()*0.3;
            _this.scale = 0.1+Math.random()*0.3;
            _this.velocity = Math.random();
        }

        this.draw = function() {
            if(_this.alpha >= 0.005){
               _this.alpha -= 0.005;
            } else {
                _this.alpha = 0;
            }
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(_this.coords[0].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[0].y+_this.pos.y);
            ctx.lineTo(_this.coords[1].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[1].y+_this.pos.y);
            ctx.lineTo(_this.coords[2].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[2].y+_this.pos.y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+_this.color+','+ _this.alpha+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };

        this.init = init;
    }

})();
```

Ive checked this stackoverflow: [Create equilateral triangle in the middle of canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935930/create-equilateral-triangle-in-the-middle-of-canvas)

Here the full snippet:

```js
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, circles, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: 0, y: height};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create particles
        circles = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width*0.5; x++) {
            var c = new Circle();
            circles.push(c);
        }
        animate();
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in circles) {
                circles[i].draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function Circle() {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = {};
            init();
            console.log(_this);
        })();

        function init() {
            _this.pos.x = Math.random()*width;
            _this.pos.y = height+Math.random()*100;
            _this.alpha = 0.1+Math.random()*0.3;
            _this.scale = 0.1+Math.random()*0.3;
            _this.velocity = Math.random();
        }

        this.draw = function() {
            if(_this.alpha <= 0) {
                init();
            }
            _this.pos.y -= _this.velocity;
            _this.alpha -= 0.0005;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.scale*10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,'+ _this.alpha+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

})();
```

If you know the solution.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try something? Please show what you tried... Did you change the `ctx.beginPath();` section using the code from the answer you linked and it did not work?

Comment: I have tried adding this:

Comment: Your making circles with `new Circle()`. Change it's `draw()` function to draw a triangle (using `ctx.lineTo` and not `ctx.arc`). Along with that after you change it you might want to name it `Triangle` instead.

Comment: Oke changed it. But there is still an error somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version of the relevant part of the code (it draws the triangles), if you need to understand these methods, check the [canvas API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x - (width/2) , y + height);
ctx.lineTo(x + (width/2) , y + height);
ctx.fill();
```

It's starts at the top of the triangle (Y axis goes top to bottom), then it goes to the left bottom corner and it ends at the right bottom.

```
    1 = (x, y)
  .   .
 .     .
2 . . . 3 = (x + (width/2), y + height)
```

```js
(function() {

  var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, circles, target, animateHeader = true;

  // Main
  initHeader();
  addListeners();

  function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    target = {x: 0, y: height};

    largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create particles
    circles = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      var c = new Circle();
      circles.push(c);
    }
    animate();
  }

  // Event handling
  function addListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  }

  function scrollCheck() {
    animateHeader = document.body.scrollTop < height;
  }

  function resize() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
  }

  function animate() {
    if(animateHeader) {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
      for(var i in circles) {
        circles[i].draw();
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  // Canvas manipulation
  function Circle() {
    var _this = this;

    // constructor
    (function() {
      _this.pos = {};
      init();
      //console.log(_this);
    })();

    function init() {
      _this.pos.x = Math.random()*width;
      _this.pos.y = height+Math.random()*100;
      _this.alpha = 0.1+Math.random()*0.3;
      _this.height = 10+Math.random()*0.3;
      _this.width = 10+Math.random()*0.3;
      _this.velocity = Math.random();
    }

    this.draw = function() {
      if(_this.alpha <= 0) {
        init();
      }
      _this.pos.y -= _this.velocity;
      _this.alpha -= 0.0005;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y);
      ctx.lineTo(_this.pos.x - (_this.width/2) , _this.pos.y + _this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(_this.pos.x + (_this.width/2) , _this.pos.y + _this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,'+ _this.alpha+')';
      ctx.fill();
    };
  }

})();
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#large-header, #demo-canvas {
  background: #333;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="large-header">
      <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kefune/2/edit)

Comment: Give some explanation, just dumping code on the OP isn't helpful to show where they went wrong. Even if it works *"try this..."* type answers tend to not be very helpful.