# How to make slanted CSS arrow pointing to a div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a plant identification site where we want people to be able to easily locate a specific plant in a photo.  Each plant in the photo area is contained in a div, and I'd like to make an arrow (like in the image here: http://www.plantiferate.com/ArrowExample2.jpg) which goes from a point in the right plant list (the left edge/vertical middle of the text "Autumn Blaze Pear") to the right edge/vertical middle of a div located over the area of the red pear tree in the photo.

Here's a simplified version of what I've got right now, without the arrow.  Any ideas how to accomplish something like this using CSS and/or JQuery?  Thanks!

```
<div class="photoareacontainer">

<div class="photoarea">
    <img src="URL" class="photobackground" width="800" height="600" />
    <div class="highlight-region" ID="autumnblazepearphoto" 
        style="top:400px;left:200px; width:300px; height:#300px;" title="Autumn Blaze Callery Pear: ..."></div>
    <div class="highlight-region" ID="weepingwillowphoto" 
        style="top:350px;left:500px; width:300px; height:#300px;" title="Weeping Willow: ..."></div>
</div>

<div class="photocontentsarea">
    <a href="#">Autumn Blaze Pear</a><br />
    <a href="#">Weeping Willow</a><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle with canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/6d6py3z6/)
I overlayed a canvas between the links and the images, and there's a function that calculates the coordinates of the link and the image, and draws an arrow in between them when you click on it.

`$(document).on('click','a',function(){
    var c = document.getElementById("arrows");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var start = arrowcoords(this);
    var end = arrowcoords(document.getElementById($(this).html()));
    canvas_arrow(ctx,start.left,start.top,end.left,end.top);
});`

With arrowcoords being based on jqueries position and width/height

```
function arrowcoords(el){
   var position = $(el).position();
   position.left+=$(el).width()/2;
   position.top+=$(el).height()/2;
   return position;
}
```

And the arrow taken from [Stack overflow about drawing arrow on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808826/draw-arrow-on-canvas-tag)

Comment: Thanks DW.  That's really nifty!

Comment: You're welcome, to save you some headaches, make sure to set the canvas height and width directly (not just by css), or drawing will go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I used a font-awesome arrow for my demo see here https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/y3v9n0b8/

```
.fa-long-arrow-left{font-size: 40px; margin: 100px;}

.fa-long-arrow-left {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```