# How to draw arrow in HTML table across cells?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a simple html table with some cells which I create with the td tag.
Now I need to draw an arrow from cell A2 to C2 for example. 
I thought about creating a jQuery function to get the XY coordinates of the middle of cell A2 and C2 and then somehow draw an arrow.

What is a good way of achieving the look and feel as shown in the picture?

[image: Table cells with arrow]

Comment: You can try to add a floating image over the table, using css position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Comment: Thanks. Does that work also if the arrow has to be in variable size which means sometimes shorter and sometimes longer?

Comment: For this you can stretch your image, or use different images, or use a canvas, like in the solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this dynamically by using a canvas element to contain your arrow, which you will dynamically draw via the 2D context drawing functions. You can absolutely position the canvas element using javascript.

Here is sample code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100">
</canvas>



 <table>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Javascript:

```
 var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 canvas.style.top = 7 + "px";
 canvas.style.left = 7 + "px";

 var fromx = 0;
 var fromy = 12;
 var tox = 25;
 var toy = 12;

 var headlen = 10;   // length of head in pixels
 var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
 var arrowSize = 2;
 var headlen = 10;

 var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
 //starting path of the arrow from the start square to the end square and drawing the stroke
 ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
 ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#cc0000";
 ctx.lineWidth = arrowSize;
 ctx.stroke();

 //starting a new path from the head of the arrow to one of the sides of the point
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);
 ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

 //path from the side point of the arrow, to the other side point
 ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/7));

 //path from the side point back to the tip of the arrow, and then again to the opposite side point
 ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
 ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

 //draws the paths created above
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#cc0000";
 ctx.lineWidth = arrowSize;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#cc0000";
 ctx.fill();
```

CSS:

```
 #canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
 }
```

You can programmatically obtain the positioning information of your table elements in order to set the correct values for fromx, fromy, etc., and for setting canvas.style.top and canvas.style.left.

I borrowed the arrow drawing code from [Draw arrow on canvas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808826/draw-arrow-on-canvas-tag)

Comment: if you did this, could you still get mouse events for the table cells? like hover? or would the canvas lay on top of the table, blocking the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

First, we can get the center of the cells relative to the document. Then, we can simply draw an arrow from the beginning to the end on a canvas (relative to the document). The trick is to set `pointer-events: none` on the canvas so we do not accidentally interact with it.

```js
// gets the center of a table cell relative to the document
function getCellCenter(table, row, column) {
  var tableRow = $(table).find('tr')[row];
  var tableCell = $(tableRow).find('td')[column];

  var offset = $(tableCell).offset();
  var width = $(tableCell).innerWidth();
  var height = $(tableCell).innerHeight();
  
  return {
    x: offset.left + width / 2,
    y: offset.top + height / 2
  }
}

// draws an arrow on the document from the start to the end offsets
function drawArrow(start, end) {

  // create a canvas to draw the arrow on
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = $('body').innerWidth();
  canvas.height = $('body').innerHeight();
  $(canvas).css('position', 'absolute');
  $(canvas).css('pointer-events', 'none');
  $(canvas).css('top', '0');
  $(canvas).css('left', '0');
  $(canvas).css('opacity', '0.85');
  $('body').append(canvas);
  
  // get the drawing context
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'steelblue';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'steelblue';
  
  // draw line from start to end
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
  ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // draw circle at beginning of line
  ctx.beginPath();  
  ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();

  // draw pointer at end of line (needs rotation)
  ctx.beginPath();  
  var angle = Math.atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x);
  ctx.translate(end.x, end.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(-10, -7);
  ctx.lineTo(-10, 7);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.fill();

  // reset canvas context
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  
  
  return canvas;
}

// finds the center of the start and end cells, and then calls drawArrow
function drawArrowOnTable(table, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn) {
  drawArrow(
    getCellCenter($(table), startRow, startColumn),
    getCellCenter($(table), endRow, endColumn)
  );
}

// draw an arrow from (1, 0) to (2, 4)
drawArrowOnTable('table', 1, 0, 2, 4);
```

```css
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>E1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>D2</td>
    <td>E2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>E3</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

<pre>drawArrowOnTable('table', 1, 0, 2, 4);</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: excelent solution. Thanks