# How to draw an arrowhead with proper coordinates in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have drawn the curved line using below lines of code, I need to draw an arrowhead.For this I need to draw 2 lines wth some angle and rotate it some some angle. It is very confusing to draw. I am following the post present in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808826/draw-arrow-on-canvas-tag) provided for arrowhead.

**.html**

```
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "100px" height = "120px"></canvas>
```

**.ts**

```
  arrow({ x: 10, y: 10 }, { x: 100, y: 140 }, 15); //function called on reload.

  function arrow(p1, p2, size) {
  var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y), (p2.x - p1.x));

  //curve line
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';      
  ctx.beginPath();      
  ctx.lineWidth=3;     
  ctx.moveTo(40,0);     
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(30, 0, -70, 75, 100, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(100,120)         
  ctx.stroke();

 //to draw a triangle ??
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried look a like

```js
arrow({ x: 10, y: 10 }, { x: 100, y: 140 }, 15); //function called on reload.

  function arrow(p1, p2, size) {
  var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y), (p2.x - p1.x));
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //curve line
ctx.fillStyle = "";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';      
  ctx.beginPath();      
  ctx.lineWidth=3;     
  ctx.moveTo(40,20);     
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(30,40, -0,110, 100, 149.5);
  ctx.moveTo(100,150.6);
  ctx.lineTo(82,133);
ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(100,149.7);
  ctx.lineTo(76,146);
ctx.stroke();
 //to draw a triangle ??
  }
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "150px" height = "300px"></canvas>
```

Comment: The curved lines are not same as in my screenshot.The canvas dimesnions also not matching. can you write the code only to draw the arrowhead and placing it to the position in my curved lines bottom? I think I can accept that answer then

Comment: If you can see in the link provided the ans which aikon wrote uses the javascript functions

Comment: The Last i can do is this only sorry

Answer (score 0):

You need some mathematics for this. This javascript method will draw a simple arrow head at the end of a line using `canvas`. It doesn't matter from which angle you come into the "arrow head".

```
//..come to the end of the line at some point
ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);

//draw the arrow head
ctx.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 5), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 5));
ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);
ctx.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 5), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 5));
```