# Calculate the points of block arrow in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

I have to generate a block arrow using HTML5 canvas. I found few very good answers for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808826/draw-arrow-on-canvas-tag).

But my requirement is different. I have to calculate the 6 points shown in the below picture.

I have to write a function which accepts 4 parameters:

- arrow-tail point
- arrow-head point (indicated by circle on the picture)
- thickness of the arrow
- arrow head size

and it will return the 6 points (shown on the picture) which helps to generate the block arrow.

Thank you.

[image: Block Arrow]

Comment: it can't calculate the width of the whole arrow, and height of the arrow head. You have to give these as parameters to function

Comment: @sundowatch You are correct. function will get the arrow tail thickness and size of arrow head. But my question is how to find the find the exact point (x,y)

Answer (score 0):

This was not a simple solution. I used trigonometry to find the coordinates of the points.

```js
function calculateArrow(tp, hp, thickness, headSize) {
    // basic info
    // angle between 0,0 and the head
    const a = Math.atan2(hp[0] - tp[0], hp[1] - tp[1]);
    // half the width
    const halfW = thickness / 2;
    // half the head size
    const halfH = headSize / 2;
    
    const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
    // output :)
    const arrow = [
        [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]
    ];
    
    // here comes the trig!
    // point 1
    arrow[0][0] = Math.cos(a + halfPi) * halfW + tp[0]; // x
    arrow[0][1] = Math.sin(a + halfPi) * halfW + tp[1]; // y
    // point 2
    arrow[1][0] = Math.cos(a - halfPi) * halfW + tp[0];
    arrow[1][1] = Math.sin(a - halfPi) * halfW + tp[1];
    // point 3
    arrow[2][0] = (hp[0] - Math.cos(a) * halfH) + Math.cos(a + halfPi) * halfH;
    arrow[2][1] = (hp[1] - Math.sin(a) * halfH) + Math.sin(a + halfPi) * halfH;
    // point 4
    arrow[3][0] = (hp[0] - Math.cos(a) * halfH) + Math.cos(a + halfPi) * halfW;
    arrow[3][1] = (hp[1] - Math.sin(a) * halfH) + Math.sin(a + halfPi) * halfW;
    // point 5
    arrow[4][0] = (hp[0] - Math.cos(a) * halfH) + Math.cos(a - halfPi) * halfW;
    arrow[4][1] = (hp[1] - Math.sin(a) * halfH) + Math.sin(a - halfPi) * halfW;
    // point 6
    arrow[5][0] = (hp[0] - Math.cos(a) * halfH) + Math.cos(a - halfPi) * halfH;
    arrow[5][1] = (hp[1] - Math.sin(a) * halfH) + Math.sin(a - halfPi) * halfH;
    return arrow;
}
```