# Paint arrow with QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I can paint a line with QML in Qt C++. Please consider the below code:

```
var trackComponent = Qt.createComponent("track_MapPolyline.qml");
var trackObj = trackComponent.createObject(parent);
trackObj.path = [{1,1}, {2,2}]
```

and file `track_MapPolyline.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtLocation 5.12

MapPolyline
{
    id: track
    line.width: 5
    line.color: "blue"
    smooth: true
    opacity: 0.5
    z:0
}
```

How can I paint an arrow (--->) in QML?

Comment: by drawing a rectangle and triangle

Comment: A `Canvas` object can be used. Or a `Shape`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw an arrow I'd recommend to use plain [`Canvas`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#details) component, because the Context2D API implements the same [W3C Canvas 2D Context API standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) with some enhanced features. It means that:

- you'll be available to draw any other shapes and figures you need,
- there will be a lot of documentation available,
- there are lot of solutions and/or "libraries" available to draw on canvas,
- there are a lot of [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) about canvas on StackOverflow already.

---

Here is an example on how you can draw an arrow that points you to mouse position using `Canvas` in QML:

[image: Example of running application]

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
  id: window
  width: 300
  height: 300
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("Hello Arrow")

  // Aliases declared for ease of usage of valuse in canvas
  property alias mouseX: ma.mouseX
  property alias mouseY: ma.mouseY

  Canvas {
    id: canvas
    anchors.fill: parent

    // Code to draw a simple arrow on TypeScript canvas got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64756256/867349
    function arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
      const dx = tox - fromx;
      const dy = toy - fromy;
      const headlen = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * 0.3; // length of head in pixels
      const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
      context.lineTo(tox, toy);
      context.stroke();
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
      context.lineTo(tox, toy );
      context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
      context.stroke();
    }

    onPaint: {
      // Get the canvas context
      var ctx = getContext("2d");
      // Fill a solid color rectangle
      ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0.7, 0.1, 1);
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

      // Draw an arrow on given context starting at position (0, 0) -- top left corner up to position (mouseX, mouseY)
      //   determined by mouse coordinates position
      arrow(ctx, 0, 0, mouseX, mouseY)
    }

    MouseArea {
      id: ma
      anchors.fill: parent
      hoverEnabled: true
      // Do a paint requests on each mouse position change (X and Y separately)
      onMouseXChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
      onMouseYChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
    }
  }
}
```